# How to fix a corrupted 7z archive?

Tags: compression, 7-zip, archiving

I have a corrupted 7zip file , the sources  have been deleted

and i tried to understand https://7-zip.org/recover.html but I couldn't fix them:

When I tried to extract it shows:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You have a corrupt file. Obtain a fresh copy.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do about it, if 7-zip itself cannot repair the archive. Obtain a fresh copy and pray that it's a good one.